# How to add a node attribute based on a nested index counter using FLWOR?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex, flwor

The following output isn't too far off, but the query's creating a new `record` element for each `entry` record whereas the original data has four `entry` element nodes in each record.

In this way, some data is being erased.  There should be four `entry` nodes which are children of a `record` node, the `record`; the root element is `csv`.

How can I add attributes to each `entry` element [without altering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21064189/4531180) the document tree?

What I'm looking for is like:

```
<record>
<entry num="1">2020-01-26</entry>
<entry num="2">Vancouver Coastal</entry>
..
<record>
<entry num="1">2020-02-02</entry>
..
```

so that the "counter" restarts for each record.

current output:

```
<csv>
  <record>
    <entry num="1">2020-01-26</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="2">Vancouver Coastal</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="3">M</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="4">40-49</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="5">Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="6">2020-02-02</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="7">Vancouver Coastal</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="8">baz</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="9">50-59</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="10">Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="11">2020-02-05</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="12">Vancouver Coastal</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="13">F</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="14">20-29</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry num="15">Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
</csv>
```

xquery:

```
<csv>
{    

for $x at $i in db:open("bccdc_covid19.abbreviated")/csv/record/entry

return <record><entry num="{$i}">{$x/@*, $x/node()}</entry></record>

}


</csv>
```

input:

```
<csv>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-01-26</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>M</entry>
    <entry>40-49</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-02</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>baz</entry>
    <entry>50-59</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
  <record>
    <entry>2020-02-05</entry>
    <entry>Vancouver Coastal</entry>
    <entry>F</entry>
    <entry>20-29</entry>
    <entry>Lab-diagnosed</entry>
  </record>
</csv>
```

Looking to maintain the structure of the original document above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest all such structures e.g.

```
<csv>
{
    for $record in csv/record
    return
        <record>
        {
            for $entry at $pos in $record/entry
            return
                <entry num="{$pos}">{data($entry)}</entry>
        }
        </record>
}
</csv>
```